# Plural \cref with custom unnumbered SUBsections

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, cleveref

The answer in [Cross-reference to unnumbered SUBsections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345896/cross-reference-to-unnumbered-subsections) shows how to define a custom `\subsec` command so as to allow cross-referencing with `cleveref`.

But how can I modify things to allow a plural form of `\cref`, referencing two such subsections.

Sample source:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}    

\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
%    subsections:
%
% Handle refs to subsections, which are unnumbered 
\newcounter{subsec}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subsec}[1]{%
  \subsection*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%
  \refstepcounter{subsec}%
  \def\cref@currentlabel{[subsec][\arabic{subsec}][]#1}%
  \def\@currentlabelname{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\crefname{subsection}{subsection}{subsections}    % not used?
\Crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}  % not used?
\crefformat{subsec}{#2subsection~``#1''#3} % for unnumbered subsections
\Crefformat{subsec}{#2Subsection~``#1''#3} % ditto, caps

\begin{document}

In \cref{sec:one,sec:other} we outline.  [OK, as expected]

\section{The section}\label{sec:one}

\section{The other section}\label{sec:other}

\begin{itemize}

   \item In \cref{subsec:this} and \cref{subsec:another} we ponder. [OK]

   \item In \cref{subsec:this,subsec:another} we analyze. [Does \textbf{NOT} work.]

   \emph{Want output there to be:} subsections ``This one'' and ``Another one''

\end{itemize}

\subsec{This one}\label{subsec:this}

   This is in a subsection.

\subsec{Another one}\label{subsec:another}

   Here is another subsection.

\end{document}
```

Defective output:
[image: How get plural \cref for unnumbered sections?]

Comment: Your counter is `subsec`, not `subsection`, so use `\crefname{subsec}{subsection}{subsections}` and similarly for `\Crefname`, not `\crefname{subsection}{...}{...}` which is already pre-defined by `cleveref`

Comment: Sorry about that: a leftover from a now-abandoned design choice that had had numbered subsections with the standard `subsection` label.

Comment: By the way, if your document creates a table of contents (ToC) and if you wish items of level `subsec` to show up in the ToC, you ought to issue the instruction `\settocdepth{subsection}` -- or, equivalently, `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`. If, however, you do *not* wish unnumbered subsection headers to ever show up in the ToC, you might as well omit the instruction `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}` from the definition of the `\subsec` macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The counter being labeled there is `subsec`, so `\crefname` should use `subsec` and not `subsection` in order to provide the correct cross-reference information.

The same holds for `\Crefname` then.

`\crefname{subsection}{subsection}{subsections}` etc. is done by `cleveref` already.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}    

\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
%    subsections:
%
% Handle refs to subsections, which are unnumbered 
\newcounter{subsec}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subsec}[1]{%
  \subsection*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%
  \refstepcounter{subsec}%
  \def\cref@currentlabel{[subsec][\arabic{subsec}][]#1}%
  \def\@currentlabelname{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\crefname{subsec}{subsection}{subsections}    % not used?
\Crefname{subsec}{Subsection}{Subsections}  % not used?
\crefformat{subsec}{#2subsection~``#1''#3} % for unnumbered subsections
\Crefformat{subsec}{#2Subsection~``#1''#3} % ditto, caps

\crefmultiformat{subsec}{subsections~``#2#1#3''}{ and~``#2#1#3''}{,~``#2#1#3''}{ and~``#2#1#3''}% As Mico proposed ;-)


\begin{document}

In \cref{sec:one,sec:other} we outline.  [OK, as expected]

\section{The section}\label{sec:one}

\section{The other section}\label{sec:other}

\begin{itemize}

   \item In \cref{subsec:this} and \cref{subsec:another} we ponder. [OK]

   \item In \cref{subsec:this,subsec:another} we analyze. [Does \textbf{NOT} work.]

   \emph{Want output there to be:} subsections ``This one'' and ``Another one''

\end{itemize}

\subsec{This one}\label{subsec:this}

   This is in a subsection.

\subsec{Another one}\label{subsec:another}

   Here is another subsection.

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. To fully (re)produce the OP's desired cross-reference format, you may also want to provide the instruction `\crefmultiformat{subsec}{subsections~``#2#1#3''}{ and~``#2#1#3''}{,~``#2#1#3''}{ and~``#2#1#3''}`.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks, I've forgotten that command actually. I added it according to your proposition, with a reference to you :D

Comment: @Mico: Yes, to get the quotes around both references in the plural situation, `\crefmultiformat` does it where as just `\crefformat` (with the corrected `\crefname`) does not. Lovely!

Comment: @murray - Incidentally, if you want the cross-reference labels to `subsec`-type items to be hyperlinks *and* if you want clicking on one of the links to take you to the line of the header itself (rather than to the next line), you should place the instructions `\subsection*{#1}%` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%` at the end, rather than at the beginning, of the definition of the `\subsec` macro.

Comment: @Mico: a nice improvement.