# How redefine \subsection*?

Tags: sectioning, memoir, renewcommand

How can `\subsection*` (the starred version) be redefined so as to do exactly what `\subsec` does in the following?

(Note that I will *not* be using the *un*starred `\subsection`.)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{suffix}

% SECTIONING
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection}

% ---> How redefine \subsection* to do what \subsec below does?
% Handle refs to subsections, which are unnumbered 
\newcounter{subsec}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subsec}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{subsec}%{\ss}
  \def\cref@currentlabel{[subsec][\arabic{subsec}][]#1}%
  \def\@currentlabelname{#1}%
  \subsection*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%
}
\makeatother

% EXERCISES (as list in a subsec):
\newlist{exercises}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exercises]{
  label*=\bfseries\sffamily\arabic*.,
  ref=\thesection.\arabic*,
  before={\subsec{Exercises for section \thesection}},
  resume % to continue  numbering across a chapter's sections
  }
% To restart exercise numbering at 1 in each chapter:
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\restartlist{exercises}\oldchapter}

% CROSS-REFERENCING
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}
%
\crefname{subsec}{subsection}{subsections}
\crefformat{subsec}{#2subsection~``#1''#3} % for the unnumbered subsections
\newcommand*{\crefsubsec}[1]{\cref{#1} (\cpageref{#1})}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefsubsec*[1]{\cref*{#1} (\cpageref{#1})}

\begin{document}
 
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
 
\mainmatter
 
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1 of chapter 1}

Text. See  \crefsubsec*{subsec:mysub}

\subsec{A subsection}\label{subsec:mysub}

Text.

\begin{exercises}
  \item Do this.
  \item Do that.
\end{exercises}

\section{Section 2 of chapter 1}

\subsec{This subsection}

\begin{exercises}
  \item Why?
  \item Why not?
\end{exercises}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\section{Section 1 of chapter 2}

\subsec{First subsection of section 2 of chapter 2}

\subsec{Second subsection of section 2 of chapter 2}

\begin{exercises}
  \item Another question.
  \item Yet another exercise.
\end{exercises}

\end{document}
```

The source shows more than the question directly asks about but is intended to indicate the way the desired version of `\subsection*` will be used. Using the built-in, unmodified `\subsection*` does not allow proper cross-references to the subsections through the combination of `\hyperref`, `\cleveref`, and `\crossreftools`. (Related: [Plural \cref with custom unnumbered SUBsections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383587/plural-cref-with-custom-unnumbered-subsections))

Answer (score 3):

Use `\NewDocumentCommand`, `\NewCommandCopy` and `\AddToHook`, with a recent version of LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

% SECTIONING
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection}

% ---> How redefine \subsection* to do what \subsec below does?
% Handle refs to subsections, which are unnumbered 
\NewCommandCopy{\memoirsubsection}{\subsection}

\newcounter{subsec}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{s}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\subsec}{\memoirsubsection}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subsec}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{subsec}%
  \def\cref@currentlabel{[subsec][\arabic{subsec}][]#1}%
  \def\@currentlabelname{#1}%
  \memoirsubsection*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%
}
\makeatother

% EXERCISES (as list in a subsec):
\newlist{exercises}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exercises]{
  label*=\bfseries\sffamily\arabic*.,
  ref=\thesection.\arabic*,
  before={\subsec{Exercises for section \thesection}},
  resume % to continue  numbering across a chapter's sections
  }
% To restart exercise numbering at 1 in each chapter:
\AddToHook{cmd/chapter/before}{\restartlist{exercises}}

%
\crefname{subsec}{subsection}{subsections}
\crefformat{subsec}{#2subsection~``#1''#3} % for the unnumbered subsections
\NewDocumentCommand{\crefsubsec}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\cref*{#2}}{\cref{#2}}~(\cpageref{#2})%
}

\begin{document}
 
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*
 
\mainmatter
 
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1 of chapter 1}

Text. See  \crefsubsec*{subsec:mysub}

\subsec{A subsection}\label{subsec:mysub}

Text.\crefsubsec{subsec:mysub}

\begin{exercises}
  \item Do this.
  \item Do that.
\end{exercises}

\section{Section 2 of chapter 1}

\subsec{This subsection}

\begin{exercises}
  \item Why?
  \item Why not?
\end{exercises}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\section{Section 1 of chapter 2}

\subsec{First subsection of section 2 of chapter 2}

\subsec{Second subsection of section 2 of chapter 2}

\begin{exercises}
  \item Another question.
  \item Yet another exercise.
\end{exercises}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That still uses `\subsec` instead of `\subsection*` in both the definition of the `exercises` list and for subsections in the body of the document.

Comment: @murray So what? You say “as to do exactly what `\subsec` does”.

Comment: If I change `subsec` to `subsection*` in definition of `exercises` and for subsections in the document body, it *does* work! Now I'm bothered that I still ahve to use `\crefname{subsec}`, etc., instead of `\crefname{subsection}`. In a sense, `\subsection*` has not really been redefined but just made as a alternate name for `\subsed`; I'd like to get rid of `\subsec`.

Comment: @murray Sorry, I don't understand. Nobody forces you to use `\subsec` in the document. It's often convenient to bury complicated code in auxiliary commands. Anyway, referring to unnumbered objects by number doesn't seem a good idea.

Comment: the only reason for the numbering reference to the unnumbered objects seems to be to allow proper operation of the cross-referencing commands -- but let me think about that!

Comment: @murray Referring to something non-existent is not a good service to your readers, is it?

Comment: is `\NewCommandCopy` kind of like the safe version of `\let`?

Comment: @likethevegetable Yes, it knows how to cope with the cases when `\let` isn’t the correct tool (look for `letltxmacro` for a previous implementation and use cases).

Comment: @egreg: This method somehow interferes with including both a detailed TOC (down to susection legel) and a short TOC going only down to section level. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660858/short-long-tocs-with-custom-subsection

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hacky, but since you're not using the unstarred version, you could redefine `\subsection` and have it ignore its first argument (the star). Then use the same definition as you had for `\subsec` only using `\renewcommand`, specify two arguments and change the `#1`s to `#2`s.

Since the definition itself uses `\subsection*`, to avoid circularity you'll first need to use `\let` to assign a different command to the original `\subsection`. Here I use `\oldsubsection`:

```
\newcounter{subsec}
\let\oldsubsection=\subsection
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\subsection}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{subsec}%{\ss}
  \def\cref@currentlabel{[subsec][\arabic{subsec}][]#2}%
  \def\@currentlabelname{#2}%
  \oldsubsection*{#2}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#2}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I agree that's rather "hacky." I keep thinking I need somehow to use `\WithSuffix` but don't see how.